# How to know what icon is being used in the dock?

Tags: unity, gnome, launcher, themes, icons

I want to replace the synaptic icon (although it could be any other).

I have found the [Desktop Entry](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html), [Icon Theme](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html) and [Icon Naming](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html) specifications that gnome follows (somewhat?), but even though I've been reading for a while now, the time has come to ask.

In `/usr/share/applications` there is "Synaptic Package Manager", and it contains `Icon=synaptic`. Now, I kinda guess that I maybe know that the dock uses the 48x48 size of icons, but when I put both "synaptic.svg" and "synaptic.png" (because I don't know how to figure out which extension is being looked for), even a plain "synaptic" in my 48x48 theme folder (and others, and other themes... etc, even using `~/.icons` to be sure it gets looked up first), guess what?

The icon doesn't change.

Not even after a lot of `gtk-update-icon-cache whatevertheme` both in `usr/share/icons` and in `$HOME/.icons`

I'm a bit confused. It's a freaking icon. I've `sudo find / -name "*synaptic*"`ed and all, (restart included), but I don't see the icon that is actually being used. There must be something that I'm missing...

So I turn to you. It can't be this crushingly impossible to find out what icon is being used. I'm open to consider attaching debuggers and/or dissemblers if necessary (that could be memorable), but I have made the decision that I'm gonna change that icon.

Would you please help me, if you can? I will thank you a lot.

This is Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, the theme is "elementary", and my computer is a pretty standard Acer laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the icon of an application it is often better to just use a custom `.desktop` file in the user's home directory rather than changing icon files in the system-wide icon themes. It is also advisable to not edit a `.dektop` file in `/usr/share/applications` as this may be reset any time (e.g. by an update).

A good approach to display a different icon, and without the need of root permissions or tampering with root directories is to just copy any application's .desktop file to `~/.local/share/applications`.

We can then edit the desktop file with any editor to change the path to our custom icon:

```
Icon=/full/path/to/icon  # or name of icon
```

We have to grant this `.desktop` file permission *"Allow executing file as program"*.

After logging out and log back in the settings in `~/.local/share/applications` will override system wide settings and our desired icon will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Open `synaptic.desktop` file using the following command:

```
sudo -i gedit /usr/share/app-install/desktop/synaptic:synaptic.desktop
```

and change the line:

```
Icon=synaptic
```

with:

```
Icon=/path/to/new/icon
```

Save the file and close it. It does not matter what extension has `icon` (`.svg`, `.png`, etc), the important thing is that the path to the new icon (inclusive its extension) to be introduced correctly.

That should be enough.